# How to add or remove textboxes by changing the options in the combobox in Visual c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, combobox, visual-c++-2013

I want to know that whether I can add a textbox or label by changing the options in combo box. For example, I have 2 options in Combobox. If I choose the #1, it must show me 2 textboxes, but if I choose #2 it must show 3 textboxes.Can I do something like this in Visual Studio C++?

Comment: In WinAPI or in MFC?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in two ways:

1. Dynamically create and destroy the edit controls using [CreateWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx) and [DestroyWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682.aspx).
2. Statically create your GUI with 3 edit controls and set the visibility of the controls based on the selection using [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

- Have as many text-boxes you want. But **hide** them.
- Handle `CBN_SELCHANGE` (`ON_CBN_SEL_CHANGE` in MFC).
- In the handler, show (or hide) the text boxes depending on selection.

Showing/hiding text boxes aren't good from UI perspective. You better enable/disable them appropriately. You may put alternate text when they are disabled, and bring back original change when they have to be enabled.

Creating textboxes at runtime, and then deleting them isn't' good approach. You will need to keep track of Win32 UI *handle* and/or MFC object. This approach will also need more of UI resource creation/deletion, parent-child relationship handling et. al.

Comment: *"This approach will also need more of UI resource creation/deletion, parent-child relationship handling et. al."* - Not at all. In fact, it will use **less** UI resources (or at least, no more). It may use up more computing resources, but since this is a GUI, the user is the limiting factor. It's unlikely for a user to change their mind at a rate of 10.000.000 times a second about their combo box selection.

Comment: So, you are saying `CreateWindow` is cheaper than (or equivalent to)`ShowWindow` and `EnableWindow` ? I disagree.

Comment: @IInspectable, If you are saying "don't create a resource until needed" - yes it will save. But, you can't limit user actions (nor assume). More code will be required to create/re-create controls, window handle will become invalid (if used elsewhere across code). Hiding/Disabling controls is always preferred.

Comment: *"So, you are saying CreateWindow is cheaper than (or equivalent to)ShowWindow and EnableWindow ?"* - In terms of **UI** resources (more specifically, USER objects) it is. A window that never was created won't use up space in somewhat limited kernel-controlled WND lists. I'm also not recommending to always do this or always do that. Merely pointing out, that your statement is wrong. As is your final, absolute statement (as is the case with most absolute statements).

Comment: Hence you are saying User object creation is `<=` costly than modifying its properties?! I'm amazed, if that's true, and you'd need to point me somewhere.

Comment: No, I'm not saying this at all. I'm not talking about **costs**, I'm talking about **resources consumption** (just like you were, in the statement I quoted in my first comment). [USER objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725486.aspx) are more limited than most developers assume (see [Pushing the Limits of Windows: USER and GDI Objects – Part 1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2010/02/24/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-user-and-gdi-objects-part-1/) if you need more information).

Comment: Well, then I would say you shouldn't recommend `DestroyWindow` just on user actions. Keep the handle/pointer to window once created. This way you achieve best of two worlds - create when needed, but show/hide further then. Destroy only when parent window is closed.

Comment: Oh boy, which part of **resource consumption** and **limited** do you not understand? You cannot be this incapable of comprehending basic concepts. At any rate, this is getting too tedious for me. If you need the last word, be my guest.

Comment: You don't need to shout and insult man! You are advising optimization but creating window only when needed, I'm saying don't enter the loop of create-destroy (I'm favoring you). My approach was just to create 1 or 2 text boxes, and show/hide them, you don't like it. I am agreeing your point, and giving suggestion not to delete until the end (of parent), and you are disagreeing that also. Which part of my input you don't understand? See any modern UI application (your fav browser for e.g.) - few controls are already there - they are hidden/disabled on user actions, and not deleted/created.